# Get data from JSON using custom datasource

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, json.net

First of all I'm very new to Windows Phone development. At the moment I'm trying to save a JSON file locally and next read it and use the objects.

I can save the JSON locally but now I want to read it back out using my datasource.

Here is my datasource:

```
public sealed class OrganizationDataSource
    {
        private static OrganizationDataSource _organizationDatasource = new OrganizationDataSource();

        private static string jsonPath = "organizationdata.json";

        private static List<OrganizationObject> _organizationList = new List<OrganizationObject>();

        public static List<OrganizationObject> organizationList
        {
            get { return _organizationList; }
        }

        public static async Task AddOrganization(string jsonObjects)
        {
            await AddOrganizationToList(jsonObjects, true);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Alle events worden lokaal opgehaald bij het starten van de applicatie.
        /// </summary>
        private async Task GetOrganizationFromJson()
        {
            if (organizationList.Count != 0)
                return;

            var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(jsonPath);
            var jsonText = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
            Debug.WriteLine(jsonText);
            await AddOrganizationToList(jsonText, false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Statische methode waarmee alle events lokaal opgehaald worden uit een Json bestand.
        /// </summary>
        public static async Task getLocalOrganization()
        {
            await _organizationDatasource.GetOrganizationFromJson();
        }

        private static async Task AddOrganizationToList(string organization, bool newOrganization)
        {
            if (!newOrganization && _organizationList.Count != 0)
                return;
            try
            {
                Organization orgItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Organization>(organization);
                Debug.WriteLine(orgItem);
                _organizationList = orgItem.organizations;
                string content = organization;
                Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(jsonPath,CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, content);
            }
            catch (JsonReaderException jrex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("AddNewsToList JsonReasException: {0}", jrex.Message));
            }
            catch (ArgumentException argex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("AddNewsToList ArgumentException: {0}", argex.Message));
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException nrex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("AddNewsToList NullReferenceException: {0}", nrex.Message));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now in my code behind file from my XAML I'm trying to get the organisationList.
I'm doing this as following:

```
 private void BindData()
        {
            try
            {
                orgItems = OrganizationDataSource.organizationList;
                Debug.WriteLine(orgItems.Count());
                foreach (OrganizationObject obj in orgItems)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(obj.organization_alias);
                }
            }  
            catch (KeyNotFoundException)
            {
                NavigationService.GoBack();
            }
        }
```

The problem is now that my count always returns 0. 
Anyone got an idea?

Comment: you never call the code that download/parse the json to add object to the list. the list remains empty after it is initialized.

Comment: @kennyzx I'm calling it in another fuction. organizationdata.json really exists.

Comment: Are you sure the file has been fully written out when you try and read it back in? What could be happening is the background thread is still writing the file when you try and read it back in.